# How get Windows version (on format: 2004, 21H1, 22H2 ...)?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

How get Windows version (on format: 2004, 21H1, 22H2 ...)?

See:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Windows Registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion DisplayVersion